# Build the android gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am interested in building the android gradle plugin from source. I am attempting to follow these instructions:

http://tools.android.com/build/gradleplugin

This has a reference for using repo to initialize the repository: http://tools.android.com/build

The problem I am having is that I am unable to pull a specific tag of the build,  3.2.0-alpha13 , which I want to build. How would I get the most recent development version of the Android Gradle plugin?

Separately, if I have run

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b gradle_3.1.2
repo -j4 sync
```

I get the tools directory listed, but when I change into it, I do not see any gradle wrapper build files and so the instructions for the Android Gradle Plugin saying `./gradlew clean assemble` do not work. Is the documentation out of date, or am I missing a step?